# Expected redirect to /login page for users not logged in is not occuring

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm trying to implement a fairly straightforward scenario with React Router V4 but the expected redirect to a **/login** page for users not logged in is not occuring.

The primary App component is:

```
export class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <Helmet
          titleTemplate="%s"
        </Helmet>
        <Navigation />
        <Switch location={this.props.location} >
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

App.propTypes = {
  location: PropTypes.object,
};

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  location: makeSelectLocation(),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

and the PrivateRoute implementation is

```
class PrivateRoute extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      component: Component,
      ...props
    } = this.props;
    console.log(props.location)

    return (
      <Route
        {...props}
        render={props =>
          false
            ? <Component {...props} />
            : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location }  }} />
        }
      />
    );
  }
}

PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
  component: PropTypes.func,
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

On loading localhost i.e."/", I see the url in the browser change to /login, but in Redux there is only the @@INIT and then @@router/LOCATION_CHANGE with pathname of '/'.

I'm aware of the blocked updates issue, so I have removed all use of PureComponent in the codebase to ensure it's not blocking in the hierarchy.

`PrivateRoute` was using redux via `connect` to get the logged in state. I've removed that and simply put in a fixed value of false to redirect to /login.

The console.log in the PrivateRoute is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use exact while defining routes

```
<Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but that makes no difference. It seems to be that the Redirect in PrivateRoute is not functioning.

Answer (score 0):

Downgraded react-router-redux to alpha-6. Redirect now works.

```
-    "react-router-redux": "5.0.0-alpha.8",
+    "react-router-redux": "5.0.0-alpha.6",
```